# Windows Phone TextBlock Auto Resize

Tags: windows-phone-7, size, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` in my Windows Phone app, the `Text` value of that `TextBlock` gets set programatically, so there's no way in knowing how big the string is going to be that fills it. Right now I have a static size for that `TextBlock` but when the string that fills it goes outside the size of that `TextBlock`. Then it's not displayed.

Is there a way to auto resize that `TextBlock` so that when its `Text` attribute exceeds it's size/width, it resizes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBlock` `ActualWidth` property should return you the runtime width of the text.

So you can try this:

```
< TextBlock Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
    Name="tb" Text="{Binding ElementName=txt, Path=Text}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `TextWrapping` property of the `TextBlock` to `Wrap`:

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, although I see that it solves the problem of the text going outside the boundries of the TextBlock. But one still needs to set the height of the TextBlock before hand in order to fit the wrapped Text?

Comment: No need to set the height. It adjusts the height to fit the text. But it may disturb other elements layout when a large text is passed. You may fix the height of the TextBlock's parent, if it really needs